# How do I create a bar chart to show the total number of times each winner has won a race using Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But it gives me an error message, as shown below:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

Comment: it gives  me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

Comment: Runs fine for me. Sure about the error? you are not even touching `plotly` in the code.

Comment: I tried this also import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

Comment: it still gives me the "No module named 'plotly'"

Comment: `plotly` or `pyplot`?

Comment: No error

`Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) `

`[GCC 8.2.0] on linux`

`Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

`>>> import numpy as np`

`>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

`>>> `

No error

Comment: Seriously? :) :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the title, seems to have misleading code and it's not clear what the problem was

Comment: The problem was, I was trying to create a bar chart for the data frame I had. It was giving me the error I noted in the original post. The code @Krishna gave me worked

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this bit of code from a game on November 24, 2018 at Kyle Field.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_html('https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/boxscores/2018-11-24-texas-am.html')[8]

df['Quarter']=df['Quarter'].ffill()

df_1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Quarter'], keep='last')
df_1 = df_1.set_index('Quarter')
ax = df_1[['LSU','TAMU']].diff().fillna(df_1[['LSU','TAMU']]).plot.bar(title="TAMU over LSU in 7 OTs")
_ = ax.set_ylabel('Score by Period')
```

Output:

[image]